# Example of Spring Boot, RabbitMQ Listener responding with nack

Tags: java, spring, rabbitmq

I'm having trouble finding an example of a RabbitMQ listener responding with a nack in Spring Boot.  Anyone got any resources??  I'm a complete noob, I've read through the docs a couple times but can't find anything I can easily grok.

Comment: not sure if this will help, but have you checked out [Messaging with RabbitMQ](https://spring.io/guides/gs/messaging-rabbitmq/)?

Comment: Hey thanks, don't know how I didn't stumble on that page, it didn't have exactly what I was looking for, but it led me in the right direction to figuring it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For future viewers, I haven't fully tested this yet but I discovered that a method with the annotation `@RabbitHandler` (within a class annotated with `@RabbitListener`) can accept a channel and then use that channel to respond with a nack.

`@RabbitHandler
public void process(..., Channel channel) {
   channel.basicNack(...)
}`

http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/amqp.html